# 5 point average in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I try to put a 5 point avg in my chart. I add a trendline, but it looks like this:
[image]

And then I created a new series to calculate there the avg. and this looks like this:
[image]

but I would like to show this in a 5 point average. How can I do this?

Comment: 5 point average = average of the last 5 points?

Comment: This would appear to have nothing to do with SQL, so I removed the tag.

Comment: yes average of the last 5 points

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my experience with Excel, not reporting services, but it is probably the same problem.

Your chart is probably a *scatter* plot rather than a *line* chart (note: this is Excel terminology).  A scatter plot does not have an intrinsic ordering in the data.  A line chart does.

The solution (for a scatter plot) is simply to sort the data by the x-values.  The same will probably work for you.  If you are pulling the data from a database, then `order by` can accomplish this.  Otherwise, you can sort the data in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this post](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/rolling-average.html) as a starting point you can see that it is possible to calculate a moving average for a chart using the SQL query that pulls the data from the database.

For example, using this table in my database called `mySalesTable`

```
myDate      sales   myDate      sales   myDate      sales
----------  ------  ----------  ------  ----------  ------
01/01/2015  456     16/01/2015  546     31/01/2015  658
02/01/2015  487     17/01/2015  12      01/02/2015  121
03/01/2015  245     18/01/2015  62      02/02/2015  654
04/01/2015  812     19/01/2015  516     03/02/2015  261
05/01/2015  333     20/01/2015  1       04/02/2015  892
06/01/2015  449     21/01/2015  65      05/02/2015  982
07/01/2015  827     22/01/2015  15      06/02/2015  218
08/01/2015  569     23/01/2015  656     07/02/2015  212
09/01/2015  538     24/01/2015  25      08/02/2015  312
10/01/2015  455     25/01/2015  549     09/02/2015  21
11/01/2015  458     26/01/2015  261         
12/01/2015  542     27/01/2015  21          
13/01/2015  549     28/01/2015  21          
14/01/2015  432     29/01/2015  61          
15/01/2015  685     30/01/2015  321
```

You can pull out this data, and create a Moving average based on the last 5 dates by using the following query for your dataset

```
SELECT mst.myDate, mst.sales, avg(mst_past.sales) AS moving_average
FROM mySalesTable mst
JOIN mySalesTable as mst_past
ON mst_past.myDate
BETWEEN DATEADD(D, -4, mst.myDate) AND mst.myDate
GROUP BY mst.myDate, mst.sales
ORDER BY mst.myDate ASC
```

This is effectively joining a sub-table for each row consisting of the previous 4 dates and the current date, and finds the average for these dates, outputting that as the column `moving_average`

You can then chart both these fields as normal, to give the following output (with the data table so you and see the actual calculated moving average)

[image]

Hopefully this will help you.  Please let me know if you require further assistance